# How to send email to myself when a condition is met on Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a way to send an email to myself using a script when a condition is met on a google sheet. I have no idea where to start on this one. What I want to do is when column "i" changes to "Re-apply PGR" instead of "None" to email me when it changes. Here is a copy link to my project if it helps https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EkCBCxLIZBToFkdnBpBZenZOsqEg5KaDXVB6nrbEbt0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If that change is initiated by a user doing something like editing a cell or adding a row then you may be able to use onEdit or onChange triggers.  If however that change in initiated  by another script or a spreadsheet formula then there is no way to generate a trigger for that.

Comment: There is calculation everywhere in the spreadsheet, it is difficult to see where the inductor is! You need to apply onEdit where the original cell is edited manually and gives the change you need to capture. Agree with Cooper.

Comment: Start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers and  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable. If you need further help please add more details i.e. how the values are changed (are they manually entered?, are calculated?, ...) and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

#### Basic onEdit code

If the change is caused by a user edit then you can use the onEdit trigger.[

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "High Low Temp Option" && e.range.columnStart == 9 && e.range.rowStart > 11 && e.value == "Re-apply PGR" ) {
    //Send email code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function checkValue()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("High Low Temp Option");

var valueToCheck = sheet.getRange("I:I").getValue();

if(valueToCheck="Re-apply PGR")
{
  MailApp.sendEmail("YOUREMAIL@Email.com","Testing test","1231323"+ valueToCheck+ ".");
}
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).